# How to use a heroku app that already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please help me, 
when I want to upload an rails app to heroku I do this sequence and works creating a new project on heroku

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init" 
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

and then I get a new url like http://-somethingdiferent-.herokuapp.com each time that I need to deploy an project

I dont know how to use that project later without creating other new heroku project
I was thinking to use something like pull of git, but I dont know how is the pull on heroku, maybe -git pull heroku master? but in that case, how can I pull the same project?

please I will like if you know the sequence or any tutorial?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to create an app first

```
# run this command from the app folder to create a new app
$ heroku open --app the-app-name

# Add it to the remote
$ heroku git:remote -a the-app-name

# push app to heroku
$ git push heroku master
```

`the-app-name` shall be replaced by the application name.

one can find more useful stuff [here](https://github.com/jonibatista/ballin-brain/wiki/Heroku).